# How to migrate htmlarea userElements to CKEditor in TYPO3 8.7?

Tags: ckeditor, typo3, rte, typo3-8.7.x

I need some pointers how to migrate userElements from htmlarea_rte in TYPO3 7.6 to CKEditor in TYPO3 8.7.

Or to rephrase my question: how can I prepend links in CKEditor with custom html?

This how my userElements look like:

```
RTE.default {
  contentCSS = EXT:mytheme/Resources/Public/Css/Rte.css

  proc.allowTagsOutside := addToList(i,em)
  proc.entryHTMLparser_db.tags.i >
  proc.entryHTMLparser_db.tags.em >

  showButtons := addToList(user)

  proc.allowedClasses := addToList(envelope, phone, fax)
  classesCharacter = envelope, phone, fax

  userElements {
    10 = Icons
    10 {
      1 = E-Mail
      1.content (
<i class="envelope"></i>
      )

      2 = Telefon
      2.content (
<i class="phone"></i>
      )

      3 = Fax
      3.content (
<i class="fax"></i>
      )
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a small CKEditor plugin to fit my needs:

```js
'use strict';

(function () {

 CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty.em = 0;
 CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty.i = 0;

 CKEDITOR.plugins.add('icon-envelope', {
  icons: 'iconenvelope',
  init: function (editor) {
   editor.ui.addButton( 'IconEnvelope', {
    label: 'Icon E-Mail',
    toolbar: 'insert',
    command: 'insertIconEnvelope'
   });

   editor.addCommand( 'insertIconEnvelope', {
    exec: function (editor) {
     var icon = editor.document.createElement('i');
     icon.setAttribute('class', 'fa fa-envelope');
     editor.insertElement(icon);
    }
   });
  }
 });

})();
```

The plugin needs this file structure to work:

`icon-envelope
  plugin.js
  icons
    iconenvelope.png`

Integration in TYPO3 is done via this YAML:

`editor:
  externalPlugins:
    icon-envelope: { resource: "EXT:mytheme/Resources/Public/CkEditorPlugins/icon-envelope/plugin.js" }`

The complete code can be found here:
https://gist.github.com/peterkraume/95106c5b27615e06dcfcb01a62b2a30c

Answer (score 2):

So your question is about how to add those styles (`<i class="envelope"></i>` etc.) to the CKeditor?

First of all, add your .yaml configuration file (see https://typo3worx.eu/2017/02/configure-ckeditor-in-typo3/)

then in the `# Inline styles` section you could add something like:

```
      - { name: 'Envelope', element: 'i', attributes: { 'class': 'envelope' } }
```

See also here for reference: https://processwire.com/talk/topic/8342-adding-css-classes-to-ckeditor/

Comment: With `stylesSet` I can add classes to elements, but that's not want I want to archive here. I want to insert the complete snippet, e.g. `<i class="envelope"></i>` and not wrap any existing text.

Or do I need to create a custom plugin to archive this?

Comment: I would try with https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/glyphicons before creating a custom plugin ;)

Said that I don't like much using empty tags to add icons, I would prefer using a `:before` pseudoelement